# How to use findelementbyanrdroiduiautomator to select text on wheelview?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, android-uiautomator, android-wheel

I'm new to automate testing and currently use appium . I couldn't find a way to select text(Example 20,30,100) in the wheelview using findelementbyandroiduiautomator. Is there any other solution to do this?

Edit: Here is the picture

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to do is select the `25 Baht           25.0` from the `wheelview` by use the `findelementbyandroiduiautomator`.

as

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.view.View\").getinstance(1)").getText();
```

Doesn't work

Comment: Please give more details, maybe a screenshot of what you're trying to do.

You could use the uiautomatorviewer form the Android SDK to help you out with the layout.

Comment: I haven't used appium at all. 
I used the uiautomator framework to create UI tests that find objects using selectors.

If you know the text to look for, you could try to use UiSelector().text("25 Baht 25.0") or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you clicked in element you required & showing its id,then Just

```
driver.findElement(By.id("country"));
```